# Separate a given string using special characters in swift

Tags: swift, string

How can I separate a given string using special characters in swift?
For example, I want to separate `software company` the following string:

```
I am rafiul hasan working in a "#software company#".
```

Comment: I can't understand your question. What is your input and what is your desired output?

Comment: how can i separate and make it color or others operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extension String {
  func slice(from: String, to: String) -> String? {
    return (range(of: from)?.upperBound).flatMap { substringFrom in
      (range(of: to, range: substringFrom..<endIndex)?.lowerBound).map { substringTo in
        String(self[substringFrom..<substringTo])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Use Like ->

```
let yourString = "I am rafiul hasan working in a #software company#."
print(yourString.slice(from: "#", to: "#"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to separate a string using some characters, you can use `split(separator:)` method.
For instance, if you need to separate a string with spaces, you can:

```swift
let hello = "Hello World"
print(hello.split(separator: " "))
// ["Hello", "World"]
```

Note that the result is `[Substring]`, not `[String]`. If you need string, you can cast them: `hello.split(separator: " ").map(String.init)`.

In your example, you need to separate your string by `#` and `"`. If you have multiple conditions, you can use `string.split(_ whereSeparator:)` method. From your question,

```swift
let string = "I am rafiul hasan working in a \"#software company#\""
print(string.split { ["\"", "#"].contains($0) })
// ["I am rafiul hasan working in a ", "software company"]
```

In your comment, you mentioned adding a foreground color to the resulting string.
If you are processing a `String` to put it on, e.g., `UILabel`, you can just use `textColor` attribute.
However, if you have a long string which needs different formatting for each part of it, you need to use `NSAttributedString` or `NSMutableAttributedString`. The name tells the difference about the two.

Using your example, if I want to make `software company` to have color `UIColor.red` and the first part of the string `UIColor.darkGray`, you can do

```swift
let string = "I am rafiul hasan working in a \"#software company#\""
let splitted = string.split { $0 == "\"" || $0 == "#" }.map(String.init)

let firstAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
  .foregroundColor: UIColor.darkGray
]
let firstAttributedString = NSAttributedString(
  string: splitted[0],
  attributes: firstAttributes)

let secondAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
  .foregroundColor: UIColor.red
]
let secondAttributedString = NSAttributedString(
  string: splitted[1],
  attributes: secondAttributes)

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(
  attributedString: firstAttributedString)
attributedString.append(secondAttributedString)

// Use your attributedString to set it as `attributedText`
let label = UILabel()
label.attributedText = attributedString
...
```